# How to remove duplicate column names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, data.table, tidyverse

I've got a big data frame, and like to remove the duplicate column

For simplicity, let's pretend this is my data:

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c("Aa","Aa","Ba","Ca","Da"), id2 = c(2,1,4,5,10), location=c(351,261,101,91,51), comment=c(35,26,10,9,5), comment=c(5,16,25,14,11), hight=c(15,21,5,19,18), check.names = FALSE)
```

I can remove the duplicate column name "comment" using:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(colnames(df))]
```

However, when I apply same code in my real dataframe it returns an error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(SNV_wild, !duplicated(colnames(SNV_wild))) : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 1883 but there are 60483 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.
```

Sorry, I can't post real data since it is quite large which you can see in error.

How can I troubleshoot this - I have gone through all columns names and there are duplicate column name.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you get the same error with `df[, !duplicated(colnames(df))]` ?

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you sir for your help. It returns logical value "TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE........" I do not know much unlike you but just a suggestion if we can get the duplicate column number like 5, 6, 7... etc and then do the subset like  subset(df, select = -c(5, 6, 7......))

Comment: You have a data.table which is different from standard data.frame. You can see this with `class(df)`...

Comment: @sindri_baldur Yes it is working now I changed the class to data.frame from data.table and data.frame. Thank all of you

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you sir It is working now.  I changed the class to data.frame from data.table and data.frame. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your real dataframe is of class `data.table`, while your small example is not. You can try:

```
df[,!duplicated(colnames(df)), with=F]
```

Comment: Also: `df[, .SD, .SDcols = !duplicated(names(df))]`

Comment: Nice @sindri_baldur, I prefer your solution, actually. I don't like `with=F` :)

Comment: @langtang Thanks, changed the class to data.frame from data.table and data.frame. Working